# Should I switch thumbs when C4 switches from bass clef and treble cleff?

Tags: self-learning, digital-piano

I just purchased a digital piano, and playing some synthesia to get a feel for it. I am using default settings where notes for right hand is shown in green, and notes for left hand shown in blue. Game suggest that I should switch my thumbs for C4 as shown below.

[image]

I am feeling more comfortable keeping my right hand thumb on C4, but I don't want to acquire bad habits. For cases like this, is it recommended to keep my finger fixed, or should I switch?

Answer (score 1):

If you are playing 'real' music you can play the C with any finger you want on either hand, in fact one would normally play that whole melody with one hand. But you're trying to learn: if the course you are following is didactically good, you should probably use the fingerings they suggest, at least for the beginning.

Comment: That is an excellent answer. Personally I know of 2 piano methods which start that way with the thumbs on the middle C. It works very well for beginners. There are also other great methods of course, but stick to one method at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

In real life this would very likely all be played with the same hand.   However, as an elementary exercise you're being encouraged to get used to hand positions where either thumb is ready to play Middle C.   Go with it.